# How to access ng-minlength and ng-maxlength using ng-model name

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to access/use the min and max using ng-model, since I am not having form name and input field name to access the error/valid scope.

```
<input type="text" ng-minlength="10"  ng-maxlength="30"  ng-model="value.x" >
    <p ng-if="value.x.$error" class="help-block">Please enter above {{minlength}} characters</p>
    <p ng-if="value.x.$error" class="help-block">Please enter below {{maxlength}} characters</p>
```

Comment: You again. Didn't you ask this same question 15 hours ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the length of `value.x`

```
<input type="text" ng-minlength="10"  ng-maxlength="30"  ng-model="value.x" >
    <p ng-if="value.x.length < 10" class="help-block">Please enter above {{minlength}} characters</p>
    <p ng-if="value.x.length > 30" class="help-block">Please enter below {{maxlength}} characters</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess these is some issue with ng-minlength and ng-maxlength. They are not working at my end. Try below code which is working at my end.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value.x" />
<p ng-if="value.x.length < minlength" >Please enter above {{minlength}} characters</p>
<p ng-if="value.x.length > maxlength" >Please enter below {{maxlength}} characters</p>
```

Angularjs

```
$scope.value = {x:10};
$scope.minlength = 5;
$scope.maxlength = 10;
```

And check this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3669